# Get the Total and pass to View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to create a view of request details and the Total Amount that each request has.

This is how I create my View Model

```
public class ApprovedMedicals
    {
        public int ReqId { get; set; }
        public int  EmpNo { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string ApprovedMedicalNo { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

To get and assign the data to this I'm using 3 database tables. `AppRequest` is the main `Medical` is connected via Foreign key of `AppRequest` and `MedicalExpences` Connected via `Medical`.
So one request may have 1 or more records in `MedicalExpences` table. So I want to get the sum of the `AmountClaimed`from that table and assign it to the `Total Amount` View Model property. I'm Stuck within how to calculate the sum and assign it to the column part. Can you help me here, please?

```
List < ApprovedMedicals > report = (from a in db.AppRequest 
                                    join m in db.Medical on a.Id equals m.Req_Id 
                                    join me in db.MedicalExpences on m.Id equals me.Medic_Id 
                                    join e in db.CreateEmployee on a.Create_By equals e.Id 
                                    join c in db.CreateCompany on e.CompanyId equals c.Id 
                                    where m.HodApproval == true && m.HodApprovedDate <= 
                                    ToDate && m.HodApprovedDate >= FromDate

                                    select new ApprovedMedicals {
                                    EmpNo = e.EmpNo,
                                    EmpName = e.EmpName,
                                    Company = c.CompanyName,
                                    ApprovedMedicalNo = m.ApproveNumber,
                                    ApprovedDate = m.HodApprovedDate,
                                    CreatedDate = a.Created_Date,
                                    ReqId = a.Id,
                                    TotalAmount = // Here I want to get the Total of me.Amount

                                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReqId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
List < ApprovedMedicals > report = (from a in db.AppRequest 
                                    join m in db.Medical on a.Id equals m.Req_Id 
                                    join me in db.MedicalExpences on m.Id equals me.Medic_Id 
                                    join e in db.CreateEmployee on a.Create_By equals e.Id 
                                    join c in db.CreateCompany on e.CompanyId equals c.Id 
                                    where m.HodApproval == true && m.HodApprovedDate <= 
                                    ToDate && m.HodApprovedDate >= FromDate

                                    select new ApprovedMedicals {
                                    EmpNo = e.EmpNo,
                                    EmpName = e.EmpName,
                                    Company = c.CompanyName,
                                    ApprovedMedicalNo = m.ApproveNumber,
                                    ApprovedDate = m.HodApprovedDate,
                                    CreatedDate = a.Created_Date,
                                    ReqId = a.Id,
                                    TotalAmount = 0

                                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReqId).ToList();


foreach (var item in report)
{
    var Id = db.Medical.Where(x => x.Req_Id == item.ReqId).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    item.TotalAmount = db.MedicalExpences.Where(x => x.Medic_Id == Id).Sum(x => x.Amount);
}
```